# Snyk doesn't check vulnerabilities in main code files

Tags: security, configuration, snyk, devsecops

I added my github projects to snyk.io portal to check vulnerabilities. Sadly, snyk is only checking files ending with the .json, .yml, .txt etc. It's not checking vulnerabilities in typescript, js, java, python files. I tried this couple times, same result, no change. Any suggestion?

[image: snyk output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to SAST scan in your own code, not SCA / open source dependencies, right? Then it should be under "Code Analysis" (second item in your screenshot); that's where the SAST results appear. Everything else in above screenshot are results from SCA scans.

Can you open the "Code Analysis" and see what's in the report / which file types are shown there?

Comment: Well Spotted! really this is not the exact image I have, because I needed to raise a question, I uploaded a project from my personal github repo, nonetheless, for the real project there wasn't "Code Analysis" in results, later once I enabled the Snyk Code in settings, it worked, thank you.